# Resizing UIStackView when hiding a subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a UIStackView with the config below, when i hide its first subview i want it to shrink in height rather than redistributing the height of the existing cells to fill or leaving white space.

Is there a way to achieve this? as currently it wont change in height despite hiding its contents

```
 let headerStackView = UIStackView()
    headerStackView.backgroundColor = .clear
    headerStackView.axis = .vertical
    headerStackView.alignment = .fill
    headerStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    headerStackView.spacing = 0
    headerStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    headerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Constraints

```
    headerStackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
       make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
       make.top.equalTo(topView.snp.bottom)
    }
```

Hiding of subview (opposite for showing)

```
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) { [weak self] in
            headerStackView.arrangedSubviews.first.isHidden = true
            headerStackView.arrangedSubviews.first.alpha = 0
            self?.detailsHeaderView.headerStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

Comment: Don't give the stack view a height or bottom constraint.

Comment: it has no height, if it doesnt have a bottom constraint it pushed the whole view off the screen, should the content views have heights?

Comment: looks like that might have resolved that issue actually, the issue im facing seems to be with a superview not resisitng which looked like it was the stackview

Comment: @DonMag if i remove the bottom constraint, the parent view which pinned to the bottom now cascades due to no height constraint, i cant add height constraint to it as it depends on stackview height, so at what scope do i define height here to make it adapt but fit properly? If i pin the parent view to the stackview bottom, it stops the stackview compressing again

Comment: You need to show / explain your full view hierarchy.

Comment: Parent VC -> UIView -> ContainerUIView -> StackView -> SubViews, now the stackview has no bottom, the container and uiview parent cant get a height and it just cascades

Comment: Its pretty much a case of what does the container of the stackview clip to if not the bottom of the stackview (as that limits the stackview being able to compress it seems)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not entirely clear what you are trying to do... Is this what you're going for? https://imgur.com/a/OzCP1E9